# White screen during installation

Tags: error, server, installation

I am trying to get Craft running on the Digital Ocean/ Serverpilot combination I've seen recommended here. Serverpilot is installed on the droplet and running fine. I created an app, uploaded the most recent version of Craft and unzipped it on the server. I renamed htaccess to .htaccess and put the db credentials in db.php.

I get a white screen on example.com and example.com/admin.
So I tried the alternate URLs recommended in Crafts installation guide, still white screen.

I also tried playing around with the `omitScriptNameInUrls` setting. No luck.

I also tried adding `RewriteBase /` to my .htaccess file.

I get this in the Apache access log: `82.156.127.145 - - [03/Mar/2016:01:45:59 -0500] "GET /admin HTTP/1.0" 500 -
82.156.127.145 - - [03/Mar/2016:01:46:00 -0500] "GET /admin HTTP/1.0" 500 -`

This is in the Nginx access log: `82.156.127.145 - - [03/Mar/2016:01:46:00 -0500] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4" "-" 1072 0.014 "0" "0.014" "museumrotterdam.nl"`

This is in the PHP access log: `82.156.127.145 - [03/Mar/2016:01:45:59 -0500] "GET /index.php?p=admin" 500 0 - 14106 17679 0.013 3407872 154.23% 0.00% "/admin"
82.156.127.145 - [03/Mar/2016:01:46:00 -0500] "GET /index.php?p=admin" 500 0 - 14106 17679 0.012 3407872 82.35% 0.00% "/admin"`

There's nothing in the server's error logs.

When I add `'devMode' => true,` to the config Craft does not log any errors.

What else could I try?

Comment: Anything useful in your web server's errors logs?  Or if you enable devMode in Craft's logs?

Comment: I see a 500 error in the logs when trying to access /admin

Comment: Craft's logs or your web servers? Regardless, what's the error message being logged?

Comment: Hrm... nothing in the Apache (or nginx) error logs (not the access log)?

Comment: Nope, white as the driven snow.

Comment: Did you simply try to ad a index.html so at least you can be sure your not in the wrong folder.

Comment: My phpinfo.php displays fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I've had a completely white screen from Craft I've traced it to a syntax error in one of the files in `craft/config`, so I'd double-check your `db.php` and `general.php` if they've been edited.

Comment: I had looked at these files again and again, the syntax seemed completely correct. Until I noticed a single `'` in my randomly generated database-password. Sigh.